# Externally triggering Thunderbird into displaying a wanted message

Tags: scripting, external, directory, thunderbird

I would like having a way to trigger Thunderbird, from an external script, into displaying a particular message in a particular folder.

If it were Firefox, say, I would use `firefox -new-tab http://some-URL`, and an already running Firefox (or a new one if none) would nicely fetch and display URL.  But I found no way to do something equivalent with Thunderbird, neither on the Thunderbird site or through existing extensions, and even after some furious Googling around, which I attempted more than once!

One problem, compared to a plain URL, is the need some notation for selecting a message.  Short of a better solution, I wrote a script which knows `folder:SOME-FOLDER:ORDINAL`, and behaves like an extension of **xdg-open**.  My tool inserts a proper prefix and a few `.sbd` as needed within the *SOME-FOLDER* part to turn it into an absolute Thunderbird file reference, and *ORDINAL* picks a message in that folder.  My tool then grabs the message, heuristically converts it into HTML file, and then, directs a Web browser to the resulting file (and if *:ORDINAL* is not given, it processes the whole folder instead, yielding an HTML index and many linked messages).

My current tool helps a bit at saving message references in other documents and efficiently retrieving them later, but I handle a copy of the Thunderbird message, and not the original.  So if I want to delete it, refile it in another Thunderbird folder, and do other similar operation, I still have to go to Thunderbird, interactively find my way again to the wanted message before I can handle it, and ***this***, is not efficient.  What I'm dreaming of is a way to get rid of all my HTML conversion and browser trickery, but still keep the pseudo-URL paradigm and pseudo **xdg-open** interface, to directly force Thunderbird into the correct folder, with the wanted message correctly displayed.

In previous email readers I used (Emacs RMAIL and then Gnus, and Mutt as well later), such things could be managed, and I heavily used such capabilities in scripts.  I am astonished, surprised, even a bit dismayed, by the apparent weakness of Thunderbird as a scriptable mail reader.  Am I missing something evident?  Any avenue or suggestion?

François

P.S. Of course, I agree that using *ORDINAL* is not very clever.  It might mean a different message if the folder get some messages added or deleted.  This is a lesser bad.  A better but potentially heavier notation might use Message-ID values, but then, an index would also be needed to find the Thunderbird folder containing each message.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some way to do it since Google Desktop supported it according to this thread - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=584542. Perhaps try installing Google Desktop and see what kind of hyperlink its using?

I'll add Outlook supports using external hyperlinks using the outlook: naming scheme, for example `outlook:Inbox` or `outlook:0000000007A2379547B0624691F4FB2E5468A0D7642E2000`. See http://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/ for more info.